# Conditional Render in Loop

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

This is my first ever project with ember.

I'm trying to render a language-changer component.
So far it renders ok, but I would like to append a spacer after each language as long and it is not the last one .

It should look something like

DE **|** FR **|** EN ...etc where **|** is actually a  div

This is what I tried...

```
<div class="col-4 text-right language-changer">
  {{#each languages as |lang index|}}
    {{#if lang.isCurrent}}
      <span>{{lang.designation}}</span>
    {{else}}
      <button {{action "changeLanguage" lang.key}}>{{lang.designation}} 
      </button>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if (index < languages.length)}}
      <div class="spacer">|</div>
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

I read, that the if only works on properties... but how can I evaluate based on the current loop index?

What should I use instead of

```
 {{#if (index < languages.length)}}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember uses a logic-less template syntax. It does not many comparison operators by default. Especially there is nothing like a *greater than* comparison operator. There is not even an *equals* one. Basically you can only check if a variable or expression is truthy or falsy.

You have two options for your use case:

1. Add the separator unless it's the first item. You can check for the first item cause the `index` will be `0`, which is falsy.
2. Use the addon [Ember Truth Helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers#readme), which provide a wide set of commonly known comparison operators.

As an alternative you could also write your own [template helper](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/writing-helpers/) that does a less than comparison but that would be reinventing the wheel as Ember Truth Helpers ships with such a helper.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't get why "Ember uses a logic-less template syntax". Nevertheless your solution 1 perfectly fits my needs! I'm so used to vue.js.. I really don't get this ember stuff ;)